# Why pnpm has two stores when using with nvm?

Tags: pnpm

I did found pnpm is using two stores when installed in nvm environment.

```
/Users/me/.pnpm-global/1
/Users/me/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/pnpm-global/1
```

Trying to understand, why it is so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`~/.pnpm-global` is not the store. It is the location where the global packages are installed. For instance, when you run `pnpm i -g webpack-cli`, webpack will be installed into `~/.pnpm-global`.

It is probably some bug that you have two of those. There should be one global folder, probably this one only: `/Users/me/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/pnpm-global/1`

The global store is located at `~/.pnpm-store`